# Finding 2nd solution of second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Function $x_1(t)=e^t$ is a solution of: $$tx''-(2t+1)x'+(t+1)x=0$$
Find second lineary independent solution.

I tried to do it the usual way, substituting $x=e^{\alpha t}$. But that gives me the only one solution that has been given already. I know the second solution will probably be $te^t$, but I dont know how to prove.it

Comment: Your guess $g(t)=t$ does not work, but it's not very far off. I hope my answer below helps you find the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function $x_1(t)=e^t$ is a solution of: $$tx''-(2t+1)x'+(t+1)x=0$$

Let us try the reduction of order approach, which is to try a second solution $x_2(t)=g(t)x_1(t)$. Inserting into the original DE, we have

$$
t(g(t)x_1(t))''-(2t+1)(g(t)x_1(t))'+(t+1)(g(t)x_1(t))=0
$$
The derivatives are 
$$
(g(t)x_1(t))' = g'(t)x_1(t) + x_1'(t)g(t)
$$
$$
(g(t)x_1(t))'' = g''(t)x_1(t) + 2g'(t)x_1'(t) + x_1''(t)g(t)
$$
Substituting gives
$$
g(t)\left(tx_1''(t)-(2t+1)x_1'(t)+(t+1)x_1(t)\right) + F(x_1,g,t)
=0
$$
where
$$
F(x_1,g,t) = t(g''(t)x_1(t) + 2g'(t)x_1'(t))-(2t+1)g'(t)x_1(t)
$$
The term in parentheses two lines above is zero because $x_1$ satisfies the original DE, leaving
$$
F(x_1,g,t)=0
$$
$$
t(g''(t)x_1(t) + 2g'(t)x_1'(t))-(2t+1)g'(t)x_1(t) = 0
$$
Now since, $x_1=x_1'=e^t$, that term cancels everywhere, leaving
$$
t(g''(t) + 2g'(t))-(2t+1)g'(t) = 0
$$
There are two $2tg'$ terms that also cancel, leaving
$$
tg''(t)-g'(t) = 0
$$
Letting $h=g'$ reduces this to a first order DE:
$$
th'(t)-h(t) = 0
$$
Separation gives
$$
\frac{1}{h(t)}\frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{1}{t}
$$
Now integrating $dt$
$$
\int \frac{1}{h} dh = \int \frac{1}{t} dt,
$$
$$
\log(h) = \log(t)+c,
$$
for some constant $c$. Exponentiating both sides gives
$$
h = Ct,
$$
For some other constant $C=e^c$. Since $g'=h$, we integrate $dt$ once more to get $g$
$$
g = At^2+B,
$$
where $A=\frac{C}{2}$ and $B$ is another constant of integration. Now we put together our final solution
$$
x_2(t) = (At^2+B)e^t
$$
Plugging this into the DE verifies that it is a second solution. You can verify it's linear independence using the Wronkskian determinant:
$$
\left|
\begin{array}{cc}
 e^t & e^t \left(A t^2+B\right) \\
 e^t & e^t \left(A t^2+B\right)+2 At e^t \\
\end{array}
\right|
 = 
2 A t e^{2 t},
$$
which does not identically vanish on any interval; so the solutions are independent.

Comment: to avoid possible confusions, let me just add that this method is known as "reduction of order".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I believe I was taught the incorrect terminology. I have fixed it above.

Answer (score 3):

If you have found the solutions $Cf(t)$, a good attempt to find more solutions is to vary the constant by looking at functions of the form $g(t)f(t)$ and solving for $g$.
When simplifying the equation for $g$, many terms will disappear since $f$ is a solution.

In your case, try to find a solution of the form $g(t)e^t$ and see what you get for $g$.

Comment: Thank you, right now im trying to solve it this way.

Comment: I got $tf''(t)=f'(t)$. How do I take the antiderivative?

Comment: That's correct. If you define $h=f'$, you get $th'(t)=h(t)$, which should be easier to solve. Then integrate $h$ to get $f$.

Comment: $f(t)=C_1*\frac{t^2}{2}+C_2$ Is that correct?

Comment: @Lugi, exactly! If you set $C_1=0$ you get your old solution. If $C_2=0$, you get a new one.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer, since it came first and the OP was able to solve his problem with its help. Nevertheless, it's just an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

$$tx''-(2t+1)x'+(t+1)x=t(x'-x)'-(t+1)(x'-x)=0$$
$$ty'-(t+1)y=0$$
$$y'-(1+\frac1t)y=0$$
$$e^{\int-1-\frac1tdt}=e^{-t-lnt}=\frac1{te^t}$$
$$\frac{y'}{te^t}-\frac{t+1}{t^2e^t}y=(\frac y{te^t})'=0$$
$$y=ate^t$$
$$x'-x=ate^t$$
$$e^{-t}x'-e^{-t}x=(e^{-t}x)'=at$$
$$\frac x{e^t}=a_2t^2+b$$
$$x=a_2t^2e^t+be^t$$